# Getting an Error 500 when sending an email in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am  having trouble with CodeIgniter. I have preloaded the email configuration but when I try to send an email using a function in the controller, I get an error 500. Not sure what it is. Please help!

```
public function regvalidation()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[user_admin.username]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_password','Confirm Password','required|trim|matches[password]');


    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {

        $this->load->library('email');
        $key = md5(uniqueid());

        //echo $this->input->post('email');

        $this->email->from('edgemaster@edge.xyz','Edge Master');
        $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
        $this->email->subject("EDGE | Confirm your account");

        $message = "<p>Thank you for signing up</p>";
        $message .= "<p><a href='".base_url()."main/register_user/".$key.">Click here</a>to confirm your account.</p>";

        $this->email->message($message);

        $this->email->send();

        if ($this->email->send())
        {
            echo "This email has been sent.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "failed.";
        }
    }

    else
    {
        $this->load->view('signup.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Read. Error. Logs,

Comment: where can I find those logs?

Comment: @DeviantMark check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set ENVIRONMENT to 'development' in index.php on project root then check for error log.

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Form validation should be**

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
```

---

**Missing Single quote on the `href` attribute**

```
$message .= "<p><a href='".base_url()."main/register_user/".$key.">Click here</a>to confirm your account.</p>";
                        ^                                         ^
```

should be

```
$message .= "<p><a href='".base_url()."main/register_user/".$key."'>Click here</a>to confirm your account.</p>";
```

---

**Remove first `email->send()` in your email code**

```
# remove this
# $this->email->send();

if ($this->email->send())
{
    echo "This email has been sent.";
}
else
{
    echo "failed.";
}
```